# Font Awesome en Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, npm, font-awesome

Estoy tratando de incluir Font Awesome a un Proyecto de Laravel 5.7.

Para ello hice esto :

1) `npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
--chequeo y las carpeta esta en node_modules

2) En Resources/sass/app.scss agrego esto:

```
$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
```

3) Ejecuto

```
 npm run development -- --watch
```

4) Veo que hay archivos en public/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/

Pero cuando voy a navegador los iconos aparecen como rotos:

[image: image_rota]

Que estoy haciendo mal?

gracias!

Comment: Pon el html y css mínimo para reproducirlo porque puede que sea que haya algún elemento que esté tapando el icono

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente los importas desde sus servidores?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Porque es para un desarrollo de intranet, sí el proveedor de internet se cae, no puedo no tener los iconos.

Comment: yo algunas veces lo que he hecho es descargar los archivos y guardarlos directamente en la carpeta public

Answer (score 2):

puedes cojer y descargar el paquete font-awesome y ponerlo dentro del directorio `/public` quedandote asi: `tu-proyecto/public/font-awesome`, luego solo debes agregarlo en tu **html base**  asi

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
```

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

primero instalas

```
npm install font-awesome
```

importas en el  app.scss

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

copiamos el contenido de la carpeta fonts para esto agragas  en el archivo webpack.mix.js  lo siguiente

```
.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts');
```